# undefined reference to createOpenGLCallback compilation error

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opencv, qmake

I have compilation problems when I'm using the createOpenGLCallback. I've got the follow error message:

```
undefined reference to `cv::createOpenGLCallback(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, void (*)(void*), void*)'
```

I don't know why becouse other opecv functions works fine. I'm using qmake to compile the program. Below is my configuration file:

```
QT       += core gui \
        opengl

TARGET = surf
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
FrameBuffer.cpp \
robustmatcher.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
FrameBuffer.h \
imginfo.h \
robustmatcher.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

I can add that I'm using ubuntu 11.10 32 bit

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`cv::createOpenGLCallback()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_qt_new_functions.html#createopenglcallback) is available in OpenCV's HighGUI module **only if OpenCV was compiled with Qt support**, which doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: Thanks for help. But when I uninstall my opencv and install it agian with qt support, it sitll the same error. I'm using opencv 2.3.1. Maybe there is a bug or something like that.